# Three random variables ordered in a cycle

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose we have three random variables $X,Y,X$ on the same discrete outcome space. What's a maximal value $m$ such that $P(X>Y) \geq m$, $P(Y>Z) \geq m$, $P(Z>X) \geq m$? There are no restrictions on the variables, so they can be independent.

I know $m$ can be $\frac{1}{2}$, setting $X \in \{ 3 \}$, $Y \in \{ 2,4 \}$, $Z \in \{  1, 5\}$, where each outcome is equally likely. But can $m$ be bigger, and how to prove an upper bound on $m$?

Comment: Are they independent?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - there are no restrictions on the variables.

Comment: I was more worried about the opposite: allowing them to be dependent might give a different answer than the restricted problem where  $X,Y,Z$ must be independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an easy upper bound: define

$$ S = [X>Y] + [Y>Z] + [Z>X] $$

where $[.]$ is the Iverson bracket ($1$ if the argument is true, $0$ otherwise).

It's easy to see that $S \in \{0, 1, 2\}$ and

$$ \mathbb{E}(S) = \mathbb{P}(X>Y) + \mathbb{P}(Y>Z) + \mathbb{P}(Z>X) $$

Since $\mathbb{E}(S) \leq 2$, the three probabilities cannot all exceed $\frac{2}{3}$, so $m \leq \frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you! Would I achieve this bound by similar reasoning as in my example with 1/2?

Comment: @michbad I think the bound is only achievable if the variables are not independent -- specifically, I think you need $\mathbb{P}(X<Z<Y)=\mathbb{P}(Y<X<Z)=\mathbb{P}(Z<Y<X)=\frac{1}{3}$, and I think that can't happen if they're independent.